# Exact string coldfusion regular expression

Tags: regex, coldfusion

I am using a regular expression to replace all characters that are not equal to the exact word "NULL" and also keep all digits. I did a first step, by replacing all "NULL" words from my string with this :

```
<cfset data = ReReplaceNoCase("123NjyfjUghfLL|NULL|NULL|NULL","\bNULL\b","","ALL")>
```

It removes all instances of the exact "NULL" word, that means it does not remove letters "N", "U" and "L" from the substring "123NjyfjUghfLL". And this is correct. But now, I want to reverse that. I want to keep only "NULL" word, meaning that it removes single "L", "U" and "L". So I tried that :

```
<cfset data = ReReplaceNoCase("123NjyfjUghfLL|NULL|NULL|NULL","[^\bNULL\b]","","ALL")>
```

But now this keeps all "N", "U" and "L" letters, so it outputs "NULLNULLNULLNULL". There should be only 3 times "NULL".

Can someone help me with this please? And where to add the extra code to keep digits? Thank you.

Comment: I've come up with this: `writeOutput(RereplaceNoCase(variables.a,"^((?!NULL).)*","","ALL"));` based on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-text-that-doesnt-contain-a-word but it's still not quite what you want.  a good starting point perhaps @adamcameron can suggest something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this

```
<cfset data = ReReplaceNoCase("123NjyfjUghfLL|NULL|NULL|NULL","(^|\|)(?!NULL(?:$|\|))([^|]*)(?=$|\|)","\1","ALL")>

(^|\|)(?!NULL(?:$|\|))([^|]*)(?=$|\|)
```

Explanation:

```
 (                   # Opens Capture Group 1
     ^               # Anchors to the beginning to the string.
 |                   # Alternation (CG1)
     \|              # Literal |
 )                   # Closes CG1
 (?!                 # Opens Negative Lookahead
     NULL            # Literal NULL
     (?:             # Opens Non-Capturing group
         $           # Anchors to the end to the string.
     |               # Alternation (NCG)
         \|          # Literal |
     )               # Closes NCG
 )                   # Closes NLA
 (                   # Opens Capture Group 2
     [^|]*           # Negated Character class (excludes the characters within)
                       # None of: |
                       # * repeats zero or more times
 )                   # Closes CG2
 (?=                 # Opens LA
     $               # Anchors to the end to the string.
 |                   # Alternation (LA)
     \|              # Literal |
 )                   # Closes LA
```

[Regex101.com demo](https://regex101.com/r/kB9xL7/1)

Lastly, some insight about character classes (content between square brackets)

What `[^\bNULL\b]` means is

```
 [^\bNULL\b]     # Negated Character class (excludes the characters within)
                   # None of: \b,N,U,L
                   # When \b is inside a character class, it matches a backspace character.
                   # Outside of a character class, \b matches a word boundary as you use it in your first code.
```

Character classes are not designed for matching or ignoring words, they're designed for permitting or excluding characters or ranges of characters.

Edit:

> Ok so it works well. But what if I would like to keep also the digits? I am a kind of lost in this line of code and I cannot find where to put extra code... I think the extra code would be [^0-9] right?

This regex ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/kB9xL7/2)) works to also permit numbers of any length where the number is the entire value

```
(^|\|)(?!(?:NULL|[0-9]+)(?:$|\|))([^|]*)(?=$|\|)
```

You can also use this regex ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/kB9xL7/3)) to permit numbers with a decimal value.

```
(^|\|)(?!(?:NULL|[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?)(?:$|\|))([^|]*)(?=$|\|)
```

Comment: Ok so it works well. But what if I would like to keep also the digits? I am a kind of lost in this line of code and I cannot find where to put extra code... I think the extra code would be `[^0-9]` right?

Comment: Edit your original question with examples, but this might be what you want `(^|\|)(?!(?:NULL|[0-9]+)(?:$|\|))([^|]*)(?=$|\|)`.

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not work for me, it output the same result as the first answer given.

Comment: @J-P-Dude I meant to add examples, but I posted some possible regexes as an edit, with examples. I hope it helps you.